# Central limit theorem for varying random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, random-graphs

I'm reading through *Random Graphs* by Janson, Luczak, Rucinski. There is an argument (proposition 1.15) that uses the result
$$\Pr(X_n<M_n)\to 1/2$$
as $n\to\infty$, where $X_n\sim \mathrm{Bin}(N_n,M_n/N_n)$, and $N_n,M_n$ vary with $n$ such that $0\le M_n\le N_n$ and $M_n(N_n-M_n)/N_n\to \infty$.

The book appeals to the central limit theorem for this result, but I'm having trouble seeing why it follows. $X_n$ is a sum of $\mathrm{Be}(p_n:=M_n/N_n)$ random variables, but as far as I know the CLT needs $p_n$ to be constant. After some googling, the Berry Esseen theorem seems to give a bound that works, but I don't think it's what the authors intended. Is there a simple argument I'm missing?

(really, it suffices to prove that $\Pr(X_n<M_n)$ doesn't converge to 0 or 1, but I can't even see why that's true.)

Comment: Take a look at [Lyapunov theorem](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Lyapunov_theorem).

Comment: @user64494 Or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed CLT holds and yields the result, as can be seen by considering $Y_n=(X_n-M_n)/s_n$ where $s_n^2=M_n(N_n-M_n)/N_n$ is the variance of $X_n$.

To see this, note that the hypothesis that $s_n\to\infty$ is exactly what is needed to guarantee, by an expansion of up to second order around zero, that $E[\mathrm e^{\mathrm itY_n}]\to\mathrm e^{-t^2/2}$ for every real $t$. Thus, $Y_n$ converges in distribution to a standard normal random variable $Y$, in particular 
$$
P[X_n\lt M_n]=P[Y_n\lt0]\to P[Y\lt0]=\tfrac12.
$$

Comment: thanks! didn't think to look to the proof of the CLT. To show that $\mathbb E e^{itY_n}\to e^{-t^2/2}$, I used reasoning similar to http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Central_Limit_Theorem, showing that for each $t$ the characteristic function of $\mathrm{Be}(M/N)$ evaluated at $t/\sqrt n$ is $1-t^2/(2n)+o(1/n)$